# Can Flash display UTF-8 text?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, text, utf-8

I am loading an xml file in my SWF file containing some utf text like:

> गौरतलब है कि

I want to display the encoded text in my text-field. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

1. Save your XML file specifically as UTF-8 from a proper text editor.
2. Make sure you use a Unicode-capable font for displaying your text. If you choose an uncommon font or want to ensure everyone with a Flash player can see the text, be sure to embed the font in your SWF.

Keep in mind embedding fonts increases the SWF its size. The size report you can generate when publishing will tell you by exactly how much.

Comment: Quick comment on #2.  When doing the embed, make sure the proper range is chosen for the characters you need.

Comment: thanks for your reply, can you tell me what is Unicode-capable font do i need to install this font to my system.